# inverse element in Paillier cryptosystem

Tags: field

As I know, in Paillier cryptosystem, 
the encryption c of a message m is calculated as c=g^m r^n mod n^2

Now, I am wondering if I can derive g^m mod n^2 given that I know c, r, and n?

It seems that "mod n^2" operation does not constitute a finite field.
Not every element has the corresponding multiplicative inverse in Z*_{n^2}.
So, it seems not always impossible for to find a proper (r^n)^-1 to get g^m=g^m r^n (r^n)^-1 mod n^2

If so, can we find or limit the use of r so that (r^n)^-1 can always be found?

Comment: Please do not crosspost @http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/5636/inverse-element-in-paillier-cryptosystem